# How to get appDomain of manifest from Office.js

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

Hi I need get appDomain of manifest in Outlook for mac and iOS. In Outlook web I use OSF._OfficeAppFactory.getInitializationHelper()._appContext._appDomains but in mac and iOS this not work.

Please let me answer if anyone know how to get the appdomain using officejs API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manifest items are not available via Office.js API. What you've done is not documented findings, which can be changed at any time, basically just a hack. I would not advise you to do this in your project. I wouldn't advise you to post your finding in public as well, because other members of the community may follow your root and get in trouble.

Comment: Slava is right. If you need this feature, please add your request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our uservoice page. 
Learning about the new requirements add-in developers have helps us continue to enable great scenarios on our platform.  Thanks for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team

Comment: Yes I know, my question maybe should be if there was any api to get the appDomain. @OutlookWebAddinsTeam, does exist this api?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to read the AppDomain array from the manifest. Could you explain why you would need this?

Comment: I have the same requirement.
While there is Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue if customer deployed the service in different dynamic domains, our add-in wants to allow user to jump the whole page between different environments. It is too troublesome that asking user input the whole environments domain which is available in the Manifest. So we have the requirement to allow user select from a list.
Then only administrator cares about the environment domains. It's better for user experience. What's more, I find there is a suggestion posted. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-r